# Conditional not working in shiny

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shinydashboard

I am learning R and shiny and have been trying to play around with some of the code from the shiny package documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shiny/shiny.pdf). I have been trying to figure out why the conditional I have added is not responding to my condition.
What am I doing wrong as I do not get an error?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("ex")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ex <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      selectInput("n","Please Select  :",
                  choices = c("N","U","T")),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "n"=="N",
                       textInput("inmean"," Mean:",0.25),
                       textInput("invsd","Sd", 0.02)),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "n"== "U",
                       textInput("inmean","Mean:",0.25),
                       textInput("insd","Sd", 0.02))
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your condition should be `"input.n == 'N'"`

Comment: Ah yes that fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Personally I wouldn't do it this way.  I would use an observe({}) statement looking at the input of "n" and use updateTextInput() to change the value.

But this seems to work with the method you're using:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("n","Please Select  :",
              choices = c("N","U","T")),
  uiOutput('ex')
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ex <- renderUI({

      if(input$n == 'N'){
        tagList(
        textInput("inmean"," Mean:",0.25),
        textInput("invsd","Sd", 0.02)
        )
      }else if(input$n == 'U'){
        tagList(
        textInput("inmean","Mean:",0.2),
        textInput("insd","Sd", 0.01)
        )
      }

  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but this would be limited to a max of 3 choices so you wouldnt be able to use it if you had 3+ choices

Comment: You can always add another `else if`.

Comment: Oh ok I thought you can only use 1 else if. Thanks for the clarification